# Data imputation with preProcess in caret returns less observations than expected

Tags: r, caret, data-imputation

I wonder why [preProcess](http://topepo.github.io/caret/preprocess.html#impute) function from R's caret package used for imputation of dataset's missing values returns less observations than in original dataset?
For example:

```
library(caret)

t <- data.frame(seq_len(100000),seq_len(100000))

for (i in 1:100000) 
{
if (i %% 10 == 0) t[i,1] <- NA; 
if (i %% 100 == 0) t[i,2] <- NA 
}

preProcValues <- preProcess(t, method = c("knnImpute"))
```

preProcValues will contain only 90000 observations of  2 variables while 100000 is expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`preProcess` does not return values, it simply sets up the whole imputation model based on the provided data. So, you need to run `predict` (requiring also the `RANN` package), but even if you do so with your artificial data you'll get an error:

`Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 
  cannot impute when all predictors are missing in the new data point`

as the imputation can not work in rows where **both** your predictors are NA's.

Here's a demonstration with only 20 rows, for clarity and easy inspection:

```
library(caret)

t <- data.frame(seq_len(20),seq_len(20))

for (i in 1:20) 
{
  if (i %% 3 == 0) t[i,1] <- NA; 
  if (i %% 7 == 0) t[i,2] <- NA 
}

names(t) <- c('V1', 'V2')

preProcValues <- preProcess(t, method = c("knnImpute"))

library(RANN)

t_imp <- predict(preProcValues, t)
```

When viewing the result, keep in mind that methods `"center", "scale"` have been automaticaly added to your preprocessing, even if you did not invoke them explicitly:

```
> str(preProcValues)
List of 19
$ call      : language preProcess.default(x = t, method = c("knnImpute"))
$ dim       : int [1:2] 12 2
$ bc        : NULL
$ yj        : NULL
$ et        : NULL
$ mean      : Named num [1:2] 10.5 10.5
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "V1" "V2"
$ std       : Named num [1:2] 6.25 6.14
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "V1" "V2"
$ ranges    : NULL
$ rotation  : NULL
$ method    : chr [1:3] "knnImpute" "scale" "center"
$ thresh    : num 0.95
$ pcaComp   : NULL
$ numComp   : NULL
$ ica       : NULL
$ k         : num 5
$ knnSummary:function (x, ...)  
$ bagImp    : NULL
$ median    : NULL
$ data      : num [1:12, 1:2] -1.434 -1.283 -0.981 -0.83 -0.377 ...
 ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
     .. ..$ : chr [1:12] "1" "2" "4" "5" ...
 .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "V1" "V2"
 ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= Named num [1:2] 10.5 10.5
 .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "V1" "V2"
 ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= Named num [1:2] 6.63 6.63
 .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "V1" "V2"
- attr(*, "class")= chr "preProcess"
```

Comment: Ok, I think I finally got the idea. `predict` is used to get the imputed data, not the target variable based on imputed data.